# How to set a value of CodeMirror editor by javascript?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

How to set a value of CodeMirror editor by javascript command? I just need to set a text to it. But how?.. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is explained in the [manual](http://codemirror.net/manual.html), section *Programming API*:

> `setValue(string)`: Set the editor content.